# Use eclipse build variables to create project include directories, in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project in Eclipse which the base part of all include directories is different depending on a chosen platform. For example, including include/cTable directory:

- /a/b/c/platform1/include/cTable/
- /a/b/c/platform2/include/cTable/
- /a/b/c/platform3/include/cTable/

So, what i want to do is to create next build variables (window->preferences->C++->build->build variables):

- PLATFORMNAME_PLAT1 = "platform1"
- PLATFORMNAME_PLAT2 = "platform2"
- PLATFORMNAME_PLAT3 = "platform3"
- PLATFORM_SELECTED = ${PLATFORMNAME_PLAT1}
- INCLUDE_DIR = "/a/b/c/${PLATFORM_SELECTED}/include/"

Then, using the project properties, C++ general->paths and symbols->includes, add include directories that way:

- ${INCLUDE_DIR}/cTable
- ${INCLUDE_DIR}/cRow
- ${INCLUDE_DIR}/cComponentBase
- ${INCLUDE_DIR}/cTimers

That way, when changing the platform, i only have to edit the PLATFORM_SELECTED build variable, setting it to the PLATFORMNAME i want, even without remembering the platform directory name.

The problem is that the INCLUDE_DIR variable is not expanded and i have lot of errors like "invalid project path: include path not found (/a/b/c/include/cTable)". I think that the problem is the type of the build variables. INCLUDE_DIR has Path type, but i've tested using both path and string types for the other without any success. I would like to ask if someone can point me to a good approach for the creation of these build variables.
I dont use eclipse for compiling, but just for code editing, so what i want is to use the code completion and syntax highlighting.